# Ruby on Rails simple form gem form is not sending data to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I am using ruby on rails simple_form gem which is installed properly. I am having trouble with "create". Saving data from the form into the database.

FYI: a cott is a situation that deserves the support of a community.

Users has many cotts and cotts belong to users.

I removed all validations and the form will save without the data. I can output user information on the cott show page but the cott data is not saving.

When I add validation, I receive the error: 
Situation can't be blank
Solution can't be blank
Boycott can't be blank
Victim can't be blank
Violator can't be blank

```
class Cott < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :user

    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :types, :through => :categorizations

    validates :situation, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}
    validates :solution, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}
    validates :boycott, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}
    validates :victim, presence: true, length: {maximum: 80}
    validates :violator, presence: true, length: {maximum: 80}
    default_scope -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

Cott Controller

```
    class CottsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def new
    @cott = Cott.new
  end


  def create
    @cott = current_user.cotts.build if logged_in?
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cott.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cott, notice: 'Cott was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cott }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cott.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  private


    def cott_params
      params.require(:cotts).permit(:user_id, :situation, :solution, :boycott, :victim, :violator, :violator_address, :violator_emails)
    end

end
```

User Controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
  before_action :admin_user,     only: :destroy


  def new
    @user = User.new
  end


  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        @user.send_activation_email
        UserMailer.account_activation(@user).deliver_now
        format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Please check your email to activate your account.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  private

    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end


    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

    # Confirms a logged-in user.
    def logged_in_user
      unless logged_in?
        store_location
        flash[:danger] = "Please log in."
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end
    # Confirms the correct user.
    def correct_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

    # Confirms an admin user.
    def admin_user
      redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user.admin?
    end
end
```

The Form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@cott, html: { class: 'form-horizontal'})  do |f| %>
  <fieldset class="univ_padding action">

    <% if @cott.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation" >
          <h2><%= pluralize(@cott.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this cott from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @cott.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>


<div class="col-md-7">
  <!-- proof -->

    <!-- situation -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :situation,   label: false, class: " control-label" %><br>
      <div class="">
        <%= f.input :situation, label: false,  label: false, class: "form-control situaton_form_area" %>
        <span class="help-block">Explain the situations</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- solution -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="">
      <%= f.label :solution,  label: false, class: " control-label" %><br>

        <%= f.input :solution,  label: false, class: "form-control situaton_form_area" %>
        <span class="help-block">How can the violator fix this situation.</span>
      </div>

    <!-- boycott -->
<div class="">
      <%= f.label :boycott,  label: false, class: " control-label" %><br>

        <%= f.input :boycott,  label: false, class: "form-control situaton_form_area" %>
        <span class="help-block">How do you suppose we boycott this violator.</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- victim -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="">
      <%= f.label :victim,  label: false, class: " control-label" %><br>

        <%= f.input :victim,  label: false, class: "form-control" %>
        <span class="help-block">Who are the victims?</span>
      </div>


    <!-- violator name -->

      <div class="">
      <%= f.label :violator, "Violator Name",  label: false, class: " control-label" %>

        <%= f.input :violator,  label: false, class: "form-control"   %>
        <span class="help-block">Violator name or business name</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- violator address -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="">
      <%= f.label :violator_address, "Violator Addresss",  label: false, class: " control-label" %>

        <%= f.input :violator_address,  label: false, class: "form-control"%>
        <span class="help-block">Do you have an address for this violator?</span>
      </div>

    <!-- violator email -->

      <div class="">
      <%= f.label :violator_email,"Violator Email",  label: false, class: "control-label" %>
        <%= f.input :violator_email,  label: false, class: "form-control"  %>
        <span class="help-block">Email address of the violator.</span>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <!-- Multiple Checkboxes -->
      <div class="">
        <%= f.label :types, "Chosee a Category",  label: false, class: " control-label" %>
        <%= f.association :types,   as: :check_boxes,  label: false, class: "form-control"  %>

      </div>

    </div>
  <!-- end Health & Safety -->

    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-12 ">
        <%= f.submit "submit cott",  label: false, class: "btn btn-block btn-primary btn-large" %>
      </div>
    </div>
</div
  </fieldset>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `Cotts` controller's create method, you didn't pass the params where you are building your object. that's why your object  is trying to be saved as blank, and it is returning validation errors. Pass the strong params like below:

```
def create
    @cott = current_user.cotts.build(cott_params) if logged_in?
    respond_to do |format|
      if @cott.save
        format.html { redirect_to @cott, notice: 'Cott was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @cott }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @cott.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Hope it will help. let me know if it works or not. Thanks

Comment: I actually had that. I was debugging another issue and I removed the parameter. :) but thanks Rails Guy

Comment: No Worries @LeslyRevenge :)